# change state with conditionals inside a UseEffect (simple counter with hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a simple percentage counter from 0 to 100 that is updating itself using SetInterval() inside useEffect(). I can get the counter work but I would like to restart the counter once it reaches the 100%. This is my code:

```
const [percentage, setPercentage]=useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {

const intervalId= setInterval(() => {

            let per = percentage=> percentage+1

            if(per>=100){
                per=0
            }



         setPercentage(per)





        }, 100);



        return () => {

        }
    }, [])
```

Inside the console I can see the state is increasing but it will ignore the if statement to reset the state to 0 once it reaches 100. How can I tackle this knowing that if conditionals are not great with hooks setState?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `percentage` instead of `per`. `per` is of type function and will never be greater or equal to 100, `percentage` is the value that will reach 100.

This will make your effect depend on `percentage` which you have avoided by using the function. In this situation, if I still don't want to add that dependency, then I might use a reducer instead to manage that state. This way I don't need to depend on `percentage` inside of the `useEffect`.

```
const reducer = (state, action) => state >= 100 ? 0 : state + 1;
```

The way you would do this while keeping `useState` is by moving the check into the state setting function.

```
setPercentage(percentage => percentage >= 100 ? 0 : percentage + 1);
```

This might be the quicker option for you. Notice how similar these are, in the end `useState` is implemented using the `useReducer` code path as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Below should work.

```
const [percentage, setPercentage] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
         setPercentage(prev => prev >= 100 ? 0 : prev + 1);
    }, 100);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
}, [])
```

Note that `per` in your code is a function and therefore cannot used to compare against numbers. You may also want to clear the interval in destruction of component.